# iPhone 4S unlock and/or jailbreak?

Tags: jailbreak, iphone, unlock

I have seen there are several jailbreak and unlocks are available for earlier models.

Is there any trusted unlock and/or jailbreak available for iPhone 4S?

I am not sure about the iOS version as I don't have the phone in my hands now.

If your answer provides information which versions can be safely unlocked and/or jailbroken (with links to the instructions) and which are not would be amazing.

Comment: Which iOS version and baseband (aka Modem Firmware) are you running? You can find this information in Settings > General > About under _Version_ and _Modem Firmware_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Absinthe tools are really easy to use - jailbreaking has gotten much easier than it used to be. However, the dev teams are hard at work on getting their tools to work with the latest iOS version/chip version combinations so it's hit or miss with if you will actually be able to do it.

Absinthe is currently only compatible with 5.0.1 and 5.1.1 (you can see greenpois0n.com for a bit of info).

One thing to look out for is that it can be confusing but being that you have a 4S that narrows it down a bit - you will probably need to wait until they update Absinthe to jailbreak, unless you are fortunate enough to not have updated the firmware yet.

On the subject of unlocking, that's a different story - in case you're not sure of the difference, unlocking means being able to use different carrier SIM cards where as jailbreaking means being able to use non approved apps (it's a common mistake, so that's why I mention it here).

Unlocking can be done a few different ways (in the US, I'm unsure exactly the process in other countries). In the US, Sprint WorldWide customer service will unlock your phone if your account has been in good standing for 90 days (I've had 5 iPhones unlocked this way) and as long as there are no other holds on your account. AT&T will unlock a 4S that isn't on contract (I'm unsure if it has to be an AT&T phone originally) and I think Verizon Wireless has a similar policy (but I don't know for certain).

One thing you will want to watch out for are street vendors that say they can unlock your iPhone - they can't, don't waste your money.

iClarified actually has a pretty good walkthrough wizard for both unlocking and jailbreaking here:

http://iclarified.com/unlock/index.php (unlocking)

and

http://iclarified.com/jailbreak/index.php (jailbreaking)

Hope that helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This [site](http://jailbreakiphone4s.jailbreakuser.com) has some good information on jailbreaking, and as far as I can tell, it's only doable with iOS 5.0.1 and 5.1.1, and nothing greater than that.

Unfortunately I cannot speak from experience, as I have never had a 4S. But I can tell you that iOS 6 is not able to be jailbroken for any device that's not running the A4 chip ATM, and definitely not an untethered jailbreak yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try Lifehacker's "[Always-Up-To-Date" Guide for Jailbreaking iPhones](http://lifehacker.com/5771943/the-always-up+to+date-guide-to-jailbreaking-your-iphone-ipod-touch-and-ipad-%5Bios-511%5D). They recommend using [greenpois0n Absynthe](http://greenpois0n.com/) which easily jailbreaks a 4S running 5.0.1.

That's the best I'll be able to do for you without knowing the actual version of iOS you're running.

Answer (score 1):

Unlocking your iPhone is completely legal if you purchased the device unsubsidised or have finished paying for your contract. However, if you're still paying for your contract, you technically don't own the iPhone yet, so you really should check with your carrier before unlocking it.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to software Jailbreak/Unlock solution, there are low-price hardware solutions also: The small chips that are put on the sim card and make any sim card to appear as the correct sim card to iPhone.

You can buy the suitable ones in [eBay](http://www.ebay.com) with names like GPP unlock sim card or something like this. The actual price varies between $5 to $20.